# Is it possible to view html and php on same page and also access/modify html content of html dom in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<?php


$htmlDoc = <<< HTML

<html>
<body>  

    <p id="hello">hello</p> 

</body>
</html> 


HTML;   


echo "world"; 


?>
```

how to get output as : hello world 
hello from html
and world from php

and is it possible to access and modify html content in above php code like we can do in javascript like `document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML`

----follwing code sent by Niklesh---

```
<?php
echo $htmlDoc = <<< HTML

<html>
<body>
    <p id="hello">hello</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML;


echo "world";

?>
```

----- code that i tried -------

```
<html>
<body>  
    <p id="hello">hello</p>
</body>
</html> 
HTML;   


echo "world";


?>
```

Comment: you have a huge miss-understanding of the flow of server-client interactions and how a basic web page works

Answer (score 0):

Yes both are possible change your code as

```
<?php
echo $htmlDoc = <<< HTML
<html>
<body>
    <p id="hello">hello</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML;
echo "world";
echo '<br><input type="button" onClick="changeText()" value="Change Text">';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText(){
        document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML =  "Niklesh here";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why my code is not working? it looks exactly like your code. even checked in beyond compare.

Comment: I just echoed html and added one button to show new change in particular id.

Comment: You knew everything but havn't try.

Comment: No, i updated question (please look above), I wrote exactly same code like yours but mine's not working why?

Comment: I guess it was indentation error , now working , thanx